use return code function if statement from another shell script
I have shell script called script_1.sh like below
# query
batch_count_query="SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM ${db_name}.${table_name} WHERE BATCH_STATUS = "RUNNING";"

echo "************** $batch_count_query ******************************"

# Invoke the query
resp1=$(hive -e "$batch_count_query")


# return status check
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "******************* Command Ran Successfully ******************** "
    echo "Return message is ***************** ${resp1} ****************** "
else
    echo "******************* Error during the command execution ******************** "
    echo "Return message is ***************** ${resp1} ****************** "
    exit 1
fi

Now when ever the query fails the script is exiting successfully with error message.
Now I want to make some changes to the script. I want to use the return status check part of code in many scripts.
So I tried to create a function in session_helper.sh file like below
# find return status of the command
command_exec_status ()
{
message=$1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "******************* Command Ran Successfully ******************** "
    echo "Return message is ***************** ${message} ****************** "
else
    echo "******************* Error during the command execution ******************** "
    echo "Return message is ***************** ${message} ****************** "
    exit 1
fi
}

New shell script script_2.sh is below:
source /home/$USER/session_helper.sh

# query
batch_count_query="SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM ${db_name}.${table_name} WHERE BATCH_STATUS = "RUNNING";"

echo "************** $batch_count_query ******************************"

# Invoke the query
resp1=$(hive -e "$batch_count_query")   

# find status based on return code
command_exec_status $resp1

when I use the above new script even though the query fails. The job is not failing.
What am I doing wrong here. What is the correct method.

You're testing whether assigning $1 to message worked, which it undoubtedly will ...

See Why is testing "$?" to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?.  Also see Bash Pitfalls #44 (cmd; (( ! $? )) || die).

source /home/$USER/session_helper.sh

# query
batch_count_query="SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM ${db_name}.${table_name} WHERE BATCH_STATUS = "RUNNING";"

echo "************** $batch_count_query ******************************"

# Invoke the query
resp1=$(hive -e "$batch_count_query")   
ret=$?

# find status based on return code
command_exec_status $ret $resp1

And
command_exec_status ()
{
if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "******************* Command Ran Successfully ******************** "
    echo "Return message is ***************** $2 ****************** "
else
    echo "******************* Error during the command execution ******************** "
    echo "Return message is ***************** $2 ****************** "
    exit 1
fi
}

